# Link to article changes depending on module

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, menu, category, weblinks

I've created some article, and I've create a some custom modules with the list of articles (by using the **+article** button for adding a specific article to the custom module).

In a page I've added an Article category module.

I've then created a page showing both modules, and linked it to a menu item.

This is what's happening.

If I open the article by clicking on **Articles** menu item, I show the page. Then I click on the article set in the module **Articles Category**. As you can see I've a specific link and if I open it, the page opens in that link, with Article menu item selected:

[image]

[image]

Now I return to previous page, I click on the link in the Custom module that I've created. As you can see, the link to the same article is different, and if I open it the link is also different (of course) but the **Home** menu item is selected. Also, category and other informations are hidden, that's what I set for the Home:

[image]

[image]

What's happening? How can I set the same article link in both modules? and how can I fix the menu changing? What should I check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you link to an article using the WYSIWYG editor's button then it creates a link with a structure such as the following:

```
<a href="index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=2&amp;catid=2&amp;Itemid=101">Homepage</a>
```

That `Itemid` tells the router what menu item to base the page's layout on - what modules to assign etc.

- If an article does not have a menu item associated with it then the link will have the homepage's Itemid, which is what is happening here.
- If more than one menu item has the same article, then it will use the first one it finds.

Thus if you want to solve this problem, either go into code view and update the Itemid in each link to match your article landing page's menu item id, or create separate sub-menu items for each article.

Comment: And where I can associate a menu for the article?

Comment: In menu manager, there is an id next to each menu item. This is the same as the Itemid in the link.  So, find the ID of the "articles" menu item and replace the 101 in Itemid=101 with that id.

Comment: It works, thanks. But there's no way to perform these changes from the interface? Because with another module everything was working fine without changing the code...

Comment: Not using the Custom module. I believe when the Articles-Category module creates a link to a page which has no menu item of its own, then it inherits the current page's ItemId rather than the homepage's one, and so you'll stay on the same page layout.  This is why that works differently.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll study it more in details. Thanks for your help.